# How to make left and right sidebar sticky scroll (at uneven height) and to scroll left and right only when left and right bottom matches?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

If I tried with position fixed the left and alignment is changing in all windows size hence we can use the content as user wish we do not mention the height for left and right blocks

```js
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_bottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
  var left_con_bot = $('.container-left').offset().top + $('.container-left').outerHeight(true);
  var right_con_bot = $('.container-right').offset().top + $('.container-right').outerHeight(true);
  var lft = $('.container-left').height();
  var rft = $('.container-right').height();


  if ((rft > lft) && (window_bottom == left_con_bot)) {
    $('.container-left').css({
      bottom: 0,
      position: 'sticky'
    })
  } else if ((rft < lft) && (window_bottom == right_con_bot)) {
    $('.container-right').css({
      bottom: 0,
      position: 'relative'
    })
  } else {
    $('.container-right').addClass('stick');
    $('.container-left').addClass('stick');
  }
}
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
});
```

```css
.stick {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper{
  max-width :1200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 container-left">
      grid view scroll with fixed header and footer Scrollable grid view with fixed headers and footer how do I make elements fixed on screen and post scroll only
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 container-right">
      grid view scroll with fixed header and footer Scrollable grid view with fixed headers and footer how do I make elements fixed on screen and post scroll only grid view scroll with fixed header and footer Scrollable grid view with fixed headers and footer
      how do I make elements fixed on screen and post scroll only
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 pop_block"> Scrollable grid view with fixed headers and footer how do I make elements fixed on screen and post scroll with fixed headers and footer how do I make elements fixed on screen and post scroll only </div>
```

Kindly suggest me (right>left) at this state left bottom when comes to window bottom it should remain as it is and right side to scroll till its bottom match the left bottom likewise for (left>right)

the above code not working for the above condition I tried with sticky

Comment: `position:sticky`  requires a coordonate where to trigger the sticky effect . I turned your codes into a single snippet with jquery and bs4, trying understand what you try to do/stick . Not sure i understand what you're after.

Comment: @  G-Cyrillus when left div bottom touch window bottom, right side to scroll top till its bottom equal to left bottom.